# Is there an impact of using AsParallel in a scheduled task in Sitecore

Tags: performance-optimization, scheduled-tasks, scaling

I know this may be hard to answer out of context, but are there any gotchas or things to be aware of when using `AsParallel` within a Sitecore scheduled task?

We have a scheduled task in our solution which generates an XML feed of all the products in our site (~500 products, each with ~10 subitems). Will using AsParallel to loop over these give much of a performance benefit, or could this actually cause problems in other areas due to using up all available threads?

I know we can do timing/profiling locally to analyse the situation, but this does not really account for the impact to a CM/CD server which would be doing other stuff as well.

PS we're using ContentSearch to retrieve the products, not Sitecore query before anyone tells me off! ;-)

Comment: Beware your context and the limitations of context switchers. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8025/thread-scope-of-switchers-disablers-and-contexts

Comment: If you are using ContentSearch then it should be very quick to generate anyway (obviously if you have to `GetItem` then that'll have an impact). I've used this for generating sitemaps and the time to generate was negligible. If you're generating the file to disk/media library, then even less of an overall impact (rather generate on request)